# How to import a 3d object by csv file

Tags: python, scripting, csv

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to create a 3d scene starting from a csv file. I explain my problem: I have some 3d objects that I append in the scene with this function:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.append(
directory= "C:/Users/Valentina/Desktop/ku/stadium.blend\\Object\\" , 
filepath= "stadium.blend" ,  
filename= "stadium")
```

`stadium` is the 3d element that I have to put in the virtual scene. 
If I create a csv file like this:

```
name; path
stadium; directory= "C:/Users/Valentina/Desktop/ku/stadium.blend\\Object\\" , filepath= "stadium.blend" , filename= "stadium"

cinema; directory= "C:/Users/Valentina/Desktop/ku/cinema.blend\\Object\\" , filepath= "cinema.blend" , filename= "cinema"

...
...
```

Will I be able to import the 3d object in the scene by reading the csv file? For example:

```
import csv
with open ('my_file.csv', 'r') as f:
   r= csv reader(f, delimiter =';')
   for row in r:
       bpy.ops.wm.append(row[1])
```

Am I totally wrong?

Comment: The CSV seems to be broken. Your file looks like it uses semicolon-space as a separator first, and then comma-space. You also use equals-space, making it even harder to parse this file.

Answer (score 1):

With a text file like this:

```
test1;E:\yourpath\file1.blend\Object\;Cube
test2;E:\yourpath\file2.blend\Object\;Sphere
```

Where:

- First field: a name
- Second field: the complete path to your object
- Third field: your object name

You can:

```
import bpy
import csv

textFile = 'E:\\Blender\\yourpath\\import.txt'

with open( textFile, 'r' ) as file:
    reader = csv.reader( file, delimiter = ';' )
    for row in reader:
        bpy.ops.wm.append( directory=row[1], filename=row[2] )
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work! :( Do you know the problem? the console says: nothing indicated.  I posted an image above.  p.s. Is it better a .txt file and not a .csv file?

Comment: I have solved my problem! thank you so much!!!:*

Comment: The file extension does not matter so much here. But the content of it matters. Could you indicate a link for it or simply past its content in the comments?

Comment: OK... if I understand well it works? A possibility: add a "try except" around the wm.append, because some of the blend files or objects may be not found

Comment: There was a stupid error in the path . :)