# Import multiple objects using python

Tags: python, scripting, import, blend-files, linked-data

I want to import multiple objects from another .blend file using a python script. What is the best way to do this without having to import every single object?

Example of what i want to import:

[image: Picture shows outliner with different mesh items all parented to house.container and starting with "house"]

Answer (score 5):

Using [`BlendDataLibraries # bpy.data.libraries`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html?highlight=blenddatalibraries)

```
import bpy

filepath = "//link_library.blend"

# append all objects starting with 'house'
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith("house")]

# link them to scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
        scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works! There is just one problem: When importing a beveled curve (for example like this: http://prntscr.com/elvbjv) I get this symbol (i think it is for "linked"?): http://prntscr.com/elvcr7. When i try to edit the Curve Bevel now i get the error "Cannot edit external libdata" and also the animation of the Curve Bevel doesn't show up after importing.

Comment: Works fine for me, ran a simple test and it appends both curves and bevel objects etc from other blend files.  Is Curve.bevel (your picture of which shows SFA)  a linked object in your library file

Comment: It appended both for me, too. I also just ran a simple test scene but it appended this http://prntscr.com/elvrr0 instead of this http://prntscr.com/elvslb. This is a problem because the Animation data doesn't get transferred. All objects were created in the original file.

Comment: Don't know, works for me and appends (simple test) actions from lib file.  Might pay to make a sample lib file.

Comment: The action of the Curve (not the curve-bevel) gets appended automatically. Is there even a way to do this separately?

Comment: Action on both curve and bevel get appended automatically for me and can be edited, I'll repeat, make a test file that shows same behaviour and post.

Comment: Here are the files: https://goo.gl/8KeVi5

Comment: Think someone else needs to look at this, as for me your sample files do exactly as expected and append both curves.  There is no animation data.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include animation data. I updated the files. https://goo.gl/UsrCJA

Answer (score 1):

You need to use append and choose which object you want to import and which type this object is.

Some of the different types are shown below:

[image]

Once you know that then you can use the below python script which is found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38061/2517) to import the object you want from another .blend file

```
blendfile = 'D:/path_to_blend_file/source.blend'
section   = '\\Object\\'
objects    = ['myobj1','myobj2','myobj3','myobj4','myobj5'] ###<-- Add the name of objects you want to append

directory = blendfile + section

for obj in objects:  
    filename  = obj
    bpy.ops.wm.append(filename=filename, directory=directory)
```

Comment: FYI information directory and filename may be enough. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74378/how-to-import-a-3d-object-by-csv-file/74384#74384

Comment: Thank you this helped, i don't know how to effeciently import multiple objects with your script. I edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: You can look this post http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/import-object-without-bpy-ops-wm-link-append

Comment: Thanks but i already tried it and it doesn't work with beveled Curves somehow

Comment: @froggyman answer updated. You include the object names you want to append in the `objects` list

Comment: Thanks, but this is kind of what i didn't want to do. I wrote in my question "without having to import every single object". Is there really no way? For example could i import all parents of an object? Or all objects starting with "house."?